# Is destructor required for a class with structure of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, destructor

I have a class which has a struct with pointers as one of its member.

```
struct group {
   void *v1, 
   void *v2;
};


class A {
  A (group& handle) 
  : m_handle(handle)
 private :
   group m_handle;
};
```

There are no pointer members in class A. I don't see any issue (such as memory leaks) when no destructor is defined in A. I have learnt that when object A goes out of scope, destructor of A is called and if there are member classes present in A, then their destructors are called and so on. So, what happens to a member struct as m_handle above - do they have anything similar to destructor and how are the two void pointers in struct group deleted when object A goes out of scope?

Comment: There is unclear language regarding "deleted" pointers. The pointers themselves are deleted just fine, but as others have pointed out, any memory they point TO is not deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, v1 and v2 could be leaked, if they aren't deallocated in some other part of your program. So, in the destructor of A you can delete v1 and v2 (if it's appropriate to), or you can just add a destructor to group (in c++, a struct is exactly like a class except for default visibility - stuff is public by default rather than private) and delete them there. Of course, this depends on appropriateness (maybe some other thing allocated and owns v1 and v2).

Comment: Thanks..It is true v1 and v2 are allocated by another module.So we have API to delete struct..It looks like I need to call deleteGroup API inside destructor of A. That was my thinking too..But the software I'm working on does not have such as destructor of A defined and I do not see any memory leak in purify

Comment: You probably should not delete a void*, assuming those are pointers to C++ objects and not just chunks of memory. If they are pointers to chunks of memory why are you using void* instead of uint8_t or something more descriptive? The observable problem with deleting a void* is that no destructor will be called, so if it's an instance of a class the class's API is being violated. By the standard calling delete on a void* is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dan - The v2 in struct group points to another group or it could be another union containing either float, string or int. Is it ok to delete v2 in this case?

Comment: @srikrish - No because the destructor of the group you're pointing at will not be called, thus any groups that it is pointing at will not be deleted. So if you have 3 instances of 'group' (I'll call them A, B, and C) and A points to B which points to C and you call delete on A, if you implement the destructor you will call delete on B, but since type erasure has occurred B's destructor will not be called and C will leak. This is what will happen with most implementations, at least, but since calling delete on a void* is undefined I can't even guarantee that it will always work out this way.

Answer (score 0):

if `group` owns those pointers **it** should have a destructor which release them (how depends on how you allocated them). Also, are `group`'s pointers allocated with `new` or `malloc`? Are you sure you need `void*` and not some specific type?

As you have it, when and object of type `group` gets destructed, nothing special happens to those two pointers, the are not released. Ideally, you should have a concept of "ownership" of these pointers. The class that allocates, is usually the one who should deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

The structure inside the class would be cleaned up when going out of scope.  HOWEVER, the memory v1, and v2 point to would NOT be automatically cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

essentially there is no default constructor/destructor neither for class nor for structure. Compiler cannot figure how to do default destructor at all. So you must implement your own constructor and destructor always if you have pointer members that you manage. If you don't own the pointers, then you don't have to care about it, but still good practice to have a constructor.